# Gmail and Blogger account were hacked, help!

Tags: internet

just couple days ago, my gmail and blogger accounts were hacked and i had no idea how to get it back. Does anyone know to get it back? i've tried to use the "Fogotten password" option and still could not recover it. I think the hacker knew and changed everything ay.

Please help guys! Those were important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with [this Google step-by-step questionnaire on your account being compromised](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=50270).

If that doesn't work you can [fill out this recovery form from Google](https://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/request.py?hl=en&ara=1&ctx=ara&contact_type=ara). It requires that you know the exact date you started your account (note for anyone reading this: that's a good piece of information to write down).

Comment: @Lan C: thanks alot. I will give it a try. Is there any otherway though? cos i might not remember exact day i signed up.

Comment: Start with that. They'll get in touch with you within a few hours of submitting that form. Same thing happened to an acquaintance. Just fill out as much as you can. Even approximate dates.

Comment: I've tried it and got a reply from google said that unable to recover! please help if you know any other way! i really need it cos all my uni files and everything stores there.